# Setting up pagination with will_paginate properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, will-paginate

I have been trying to setup pagination properly but I am having trouble following any tutorial and getting it to work properly.

What I basically want setup is that when a user chooses the number of companies they want to appear on a page, the following loop with paginate the given number of companies on each page. If the user doesn't choose a specific number of companies/page, there would be a default value that would be set.

If anyone could maybe give me a push in the right direction, that would be much appreciated.

**View**

```
<ul class="list-group">
<%= @comps.find_each do |comp| %>
<li class="list-group-item">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <p style="font-size: 1.5em"><strong><%= link_to comp.name, comp %></strong></p>
        <hr class="divider">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">
                <p><strong>Primary Field:</strong> <%= comp.primary_field %></p>
                <p><strong>Description:</strong> <%= truncate(comp.description, length: 150) { link_to "Read More", comp, :target => "_blank"}%>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="span5">
                <% if signed_in? %>
                    <p><% if !(current_user.favorites.include? comp) %>
                            <%= link_to 'Favorite', 
                            favorite_company_path(comp, type: "favorite"), 
                            class: "btn btn-primary", 
                            method: :put%>

                    <% else %>
                            <%= link_to 'Unfavorite',
                            favorite_company_path(comp, type: "unfavorite"),
                            class: "btn btn-danger",
                            method: :put%>
                    <% end %></p>
                <% end %>
                <p><strong>Website:</strong> <%= auto_link(comp.website, :html => { :target => '_blank' })%></p>
                <p><strong>Location:</strong> <%= comp.address %></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</li>
<% end %>
<%= will_paginate @comps%>
</ul>
```

**Controller** (Where the list page is handled)

```
  def filter
    if ((params[:field] != "") and (params[:field] != "All Fields") and (params[:field] != nil))
      # This will apply the filter
      @comps = Company.where(primary_field: params[:field])
    else
      # This will return all records 
      @comps = Company.all
    end
  end

  def list
    @fields = @@primary_field
    filter
    @comps = @comps.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:number_of_companies] ||= 5)
  end
```

**Model** for the list page

```
class DynamicPages < ActiveRecord::Base

    self.per_page = 5

end
```

Comment: what if you use this code in the Controller
`@comps = Comps.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:count])`

Then, in the view you use `<%= will_paginate @comps %>`

And in the Model you set `self.per_page = 10` to set the default when `params[:count]` is not selected

Comment: I am really close to solving this, but having one more issue. See the comment on the answer below. I also updated my code a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using will_paginate. You could do in this way.

```
Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:number_of_companies] ||= 10)
```

Here params[:number_of_companies] is the number of companies a user has selected and 10 is the

default page value.

class Post

```
self.per_page = 10
```

end

Also, your code snippet <%= @comps.find_each do |comp| %>, should be this <% %> instead of <%= %>

Comment: I feel like I am really close to getting this working. Currently I I am getting the correct number of pages based on the number of companies I have, but I am I am still having an issue where all my companies are showing up on the first page. How do I set this up so that way my loop puts the correct number of companies on each page?

Comment: Did you changed `<%= @comps.find_each do |comp| %>` to `<% @comps.find_each do |comp| %>` already?